# Error C4703 and Error 4716

Tags: c

I am writing a program the that enters a date format and has an output of the same date in a different format. So far I've only worked on the first half of the program but I am stuck. I keep getting these 2 errors.

*Error C4703: Potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'month1' used.

*Error C4716: 'numDate' must return a value.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int numDate();
void wrdDate();

int main()
{

int a;

printf("Write a date to have it converted to an alternate format. You can write your date\n");
printf("in one of two ways. Either in purely numeric form, ex(09/18/2016), or a complete written\n");
printf("out form, ex(September 18, 2016). Enter one of those formats and receive the other one in return.");
printf("If you wish enter a 09/18/2016 format, enter 1\n");
printf("If you wish to enter a September 18, 2016 format, enter 2.\n");
scanf_s("%d", &a);

if (a == 1)
{
    numDate();
}

if (a == 2)
{
    wrdDate();
}
}
int numDate()
{

int day, month, year;
int day1; 
char* month1;
int year1;
printf("Enter date (dd/mm/yy): ");
scanf_s("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);

day1 = day;
year1 = year;

if (day < 0)
{
    if (month == 1)
        month1 = "January";
    else if (month == 2)
        month1 = "February";
    else if (month == 3)
        month1 = "March";
    else if (month == 4)
        month1 = "April";
    else if (month == 5)
        month1 = "May";
    else if (month == 6)
        month1 = "June";
    else if (month == 7)
        month1 = "July";
    else if (month == 8)
        month1 = "August";
    else if (month == 9)
        month1 = "September";
    else if (month == 10)
        month1 = "October";
    else if (month == 11)
        month1 = "November";
    else if (month == 12)
        month1 = "December";
}


day1 = day;
year1 = year;

printf("%s %d, %d,", month1, day1,  year1); //It says Error 4703 is happening here

}

int wrdDate()
{   

}
```

Comment: Note: `month == 01` and `month == 1` have exactly the same meaning after being compiled. So as `month == 02` and `month == 2`, etc.

Comment: `'numDate' must return a value` should be pretty obvious. You told the compiler that `numDate` will return an `int` but then never return anything.

Comment: Why not use an array (preferable in this case) or `switch` statement instead of the many `if` statements?

Comment: As to the first error, what happens if  `month == 0` or `month == 23`? Nothing gets assigned to `month1`, and therefore your code would use it without it being initialized. Learn to **read the words** in the error messages and warnings. They almost always tell you exactly what the problem is with your code.

Comment: Aside: these days you should declare `void` where a function has no parameters, such as `int numDate(void)` and `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 3):

> Error C4703: Potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'month1' used.

As this message says, `month1` is uninitialized when `month < 1 || 12 < month`. Initialize it by changing

```
char* month1;
```

to something like

```
const char* month1 = "(unknown month)";
```

Note that pointers converted from string literals are assigned to `month1` and you cannot modify string literals, so using `const char*` is better than `char*`.

> Error C4716: 'numDate' must return a value.

The return type of `numDate` is `int`, so the function must return a value of `int`. If you don't want to return any value, change the return type to `void`. Note that you will have to change both the declaration and definiton.